# can we get "Modified by" name when someone changes the record in the table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have created a table in MS Access, i can see the date and timestamp when the record in the table was modified. However, i am not able to see the name of the user who has modified the record. Does MS access have functionality to see the "modified by"?

Comment: Where do you see this date and timestamp and how is it saved? Code would have to input user info into record. Function Environ("USERNAME") can pull username from computer info. If computer is on a network, it will pull their network login username.

Comment: I think that you are referring to a property of the table that indicates when the **table structure** was last modified. If you want to get the time that a record was modified, you will need to add a field to the table, and set it to `Now()` when the record is modified.